# Android Studio add some permissions automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I have a weird question. I built my app on **Android Studio**. There is no problem however something take my attention.

Even I didn't add **WAKE_LOCK** permission or related code, built apk contains WAKE_LOCK permission. I check manifest, gradle, java, xml... There is no code related with WAKE_LOCK.

I suppose Android Studio add that permission automatically however how can it be possible and why?

And I have an **additional question**. I didn't use any WAKE_LOCK code however will it still work? Will app keep device awake?

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 27
        versionName "2.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.1.1'
    compile 'jp.co.recruit_mp:android-RMP-Appirater:1.1.1'
}
```

Edit: I checked my another app and Android Studio added WAKE_LOCK permission to that app also. Again, I didn't use anything about WAKE_LOCK.

Comment: Did you check about the android-RMP-Appirater lib? I think it may be require that permission.

Answer (score 3):

You may check a

```
YourProject/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-XXX-report.txt
```

to see where permissions are merged from. In your case I believe it is

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1
```

[Documentation for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics) states that this permission is optional.
So may be try to remove it as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36299875)